# Rails 5 retry sending email if exception is raised during the send email action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

What is the standard way or configuration option for Rails 5 application to retry sending an email if it raises an exception during sending the email?

I expect some option to retry sending a number of times but couldn't find anything like that.

**More details:**

I got [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418195/rails-5-smtp-sendgrid-451-authentication-failed-could-not-authenticate) while sending an important email, it happened only once since months but that is an important email, so I would like to increase reliability of sending the emails by retrying if some exception happens (like network issue or my smtp provider couldn't receive my email or any similar reason)

> 451 Authentication failed: Could not authenticate

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem for the purpose.

When you want to send an email you would need to call `delay` method.

```
Mailer.delay.your_method
```

it will create a record in database that will be executed in background.

If a background job fails, the error will be saved for the row. You can configure MAX_ATTEMPTS number for delayed_job server. If no errors while sending - record will be deleted from the `delayed_jobs` table.